# Dateformat won't parse String

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a Date represented as a String. An example of the String would be: `20150724T104139.118+02`

There is the parsing code:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(timestampFormat);
return formatter.parse("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'.'SX");
```

which throws error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20150724T104139.118+02"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at
```

The pattern is the same I use when transforming a Date into that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have erroneously swapped the `SimpleDateFormat` string and the string you want to parse the date from. Also the format string doesn't match the example date. You need `S` three times for the milliseconds. Try the following :

```
String text = "20150724T104139.118+02";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'.'SSSX");
Date myTime = formatter.parse(text);
```

Comment: Thanks, the single S was the error, the String swap occured when copying the code for the question (I simplified it a little), that was right in the original.

Answer (score 2):

`parse` is expecting the date, not the pattern:

```
new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern).parse(dateToParse)
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

As long as you are using `SimpleDateFormat`,  ***there is nothing wrong*** with your pattern, `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'.'SX`.

Just as an aside, you do NOT need to enclose `.` within (single) quotes i.e. you can simply use `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SX`.

### What's the problem then?

The problem is that you are passing the pattern, instead of the date-time string, to [`SimpleDateFormat#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)). Using *your* pattern, the following code runs successfully:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'.'SX");
        Date date = formatter.parse("20150724T104139.118+02");
        // ...
    }
}
```

More evidence to prove that ***there is nothing wrong*** with your pattern to be used with `SimpleDateFormat` for parsing:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'.'SX");
        Date date = formatter.parse("20150724T104139.118+02");

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'.'SSSX");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+02"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
20150724T104139.118+02
```

## *java.time*

Note that the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("20150724T104139.118+02", dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-07-24T10:41:39.118+02:00
```

In case you need an object of `java.util.Date` from this object of `OffsetDateTime`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'.'sssX");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));  //Set the timezone as per your env if you want
sdf.parse("yourDate");
```